# Manipulating strings using slicing in python to add or delete a character

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to create a hangman game in python, and one particular function is giving me trouble. I want to print the set of all available characters that the user has left to choose from. So I start out with available = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', and if my secretWord is 'apple' and the user guesses 'a' on the first try, then the new available set of characters for the next round it available = 'bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'. I've tried putting together something as seen below but it doesn't work, some characters do get eliminated but if i type in 'z' for example, it's still remains in the string available.

```
if letter in lettersGuessed: 
                print('Oops! you\'ve already guessed that letter, try again: ')
elif letter in secretWord: #this is the part giving me trouble
                c = available.find(letter)
                available = available[0:c] + available[c+1:]
```

Also, if there is any other function or method that would make this easier to do besides string slicing, I would also appreciate in knowing that.

Comment: There may be a more appropriate way to do it, i.e. using a `set`.

Comment: A simpler method would be `available = available.replace(letter, '')` instead of the two lines with `find` and slicing.

Comment: @halex oh, wow, this worked, thanks a lot. I didn't know that a replace method existed for strings.

Comment: @FatalError thanks for reminding me of the set function, i know it's more general and i'm going to learn it for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a a simpler method using `replace`.

```
>>> available = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> secret = 'apple'
>>> if 'a' in secret:
...   available = available.replace('a','')
... 
>>> available
'bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

Comment: The best thing is split the characters of the available